# testrpc 2.0.0 - cannot find module 'memdown'

Tags: testnets, testrpc

Trying to get testrpc (2.0.0) working on an ubuntu virtualbox, and getting this error when I run it:

```
mowliv@u4:~$ testrpc
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'memdown'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/merkle-patricia-tree/baseTrie.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
```

Have tried `npm update -g` and `sudo npm install -g memdown` but those didn't help. Maybe I'm being bitten by a major new (2.0.0) release?

Comment: try install `memdown` locally?

Comment: @NikhilM I assume you mean without the -g. I tried both ways.

Comment: Are you using ubuntu 14.04 or 15.10 ? I also use virtual box, everything works fine on 15.10 but when I tried on a 14.04 version I have the same error as you when launching testrpc. So if you tell me that you are using the older version, then it might be related to that. 
Good luck

Comment: I was running on 14.04.04 LTS and was able to build. I have put in a pull request for documentation https://github.com/ethereum/browser-solidity/pull/97 not sure if you still get the problem?

Comment: Have you tried navigating to `node_modules/memdown` and `npm install`ing there?